# XCode 14.1 always crash

Tags: xcode, crash

I work as an iOS infrastructure developer in our company. Recently, several colleagues have been experiencing Xcode crashes with the error message `((void *)0) == existingDocument.` This issue arises when setting breakpoints and is caused by lldb's need to calculate the source code URL and instruct Xcode to jump to a specific line in that file. Subsequently, Xcode attempts to locate the corresponding document based on this URL. If it fails to find the document, it creates a new one. However, while adding a new document to the controller, it discovers that there is already an existing document with the same URL which results in a crash.

It appears that finding and adding documents may not be thread-safe and lacks locking mechanisms. For instance, during debugging if you enter a breakpoint while simultaneously opening or switching tabs of its corresponding source code file then this issue may occur.

I am seeking solutions for resolving this problem.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [2005]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode14.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               14.1 (21534.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-21534001000000000~2 (14B47b)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-04-19 16:38:59.0906 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 13.2 (22D49)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        2E59D9F5-77A9-4454-324D-54BBEFFB334F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       3F42DEBA-451F-4B4B-94AB-E630D6AD6BE8

Time Awake Since Boot: 24000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       9447 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Notes:
dyld_process_snapshot_create_for_process failed with 5

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Signatures:
((void *)0) == existingDocument

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_create_for_process failed with 5

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x196466868 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19649dcec pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1963d62c8 abort + 180
3   IDEKit                                 0x105748b34 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 980
4   IDEKit                                 0x105748f74 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 872
5   DVTFoundation                          0x10217471c _DVTAssertionHandler + 424
6   DVTFoundation                          0x10217489c _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 196
7   IDEKit                                 0x10597fb2c -[IDEDocumentController addDocument:] + 960
8   IDEKit                                 0x105970e3c +[IDEDocumentController retainEditorDocument:] + 520
9   IDEKit                                 0x105972aa8 __66+[IDEDocumentController _retainedEditorDocumentForURL:type:error:]_block_invoke + 160
10  IDEKit                                 0x105971a04 +[IDEDocumentController performDocumentTransaction:] + 152
11  IDEKit                                 0x1059727f0 +[IDEDocumentController _retainedEditorDocumentForURL:type:error:] + 528
12  IDEKit                                 0x105972db8 +[IDEDocumentController retainedEditorDocumentForDocumentURL:documentType:forUseWithWorkspaceDocument:error:] + 68
13  IDEKit                                 0x105972cbc +[IDEDocumentController retainedEditorDocumentForDocumentLocation:forUseWithWorkspaceDocument:error:] + 180
14  DebuggerUI                             0x2c2aad6e8 -[DBGVariablesViewContentProvider _updateAutoValues] + 344
15  DebuggerUI                             0x2c2aac2d4 -[DBGVariablesViewContentProvider _autoVariablesList] + 60
16  DebuggerUI                             0x2c2aac1c0 -[DBGVariablesViewContentProvider _autoVariablesListReady] + 60
17  DebuggerUI                             0x2c2aac138 -[DBGVariablesViewContentProvider _filteredListNeedsUpdatingImmediately] + 616
18  Foundation                             0x1974a3e60 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
19  CoreFoundation                         0x19659754c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
20  CoreFoundation                         0x1965971f4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 940
21  CoreFoundation                         0x196596d4c __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 356
22  CoreFoundation                         0x19657c734 __CFRunLoopRun + 1896
23  CoreFoundation                         0x19657b878 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
24  HIToolbox                              0x19fc5bfa0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
25  HIToolbox                              0x19fc5bde4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 672
26  HIToolbox                              0x19fc5bb2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
27  AppKit                                 0x199801838 _DPSNextEvent + 632
28  AppKit                                 0x1998009c8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
29  DVTKit                                 0x101191888 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 300
30  AppKit                                 0x1997f4df8 -[NSApplication run] + 464
31  DVTKit                                 0x101190a90 -[DVTApplication run] + 60
32  AppKit                                 0x1997cc23c NSApplicationMain + 880
33  dyld                                   0x196173e50 start + 2544
```

I am seeking solutions for resolving this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest Xcode (currently 14.3).